# TLS 1.2, .NET Framework 4.0, and IIS 7.0 on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: .net, windows, sql-server-2008, iis-7, tls1.2

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server running SQL Server 2008 and a .NET Framework 4.0 Web application (CMS). Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade .Net because of the app, but I need to disable TLS 1.0 and lower. when I do that, I lose the ability to access the application unless I re-enable 1.0. Is there any way to use TLS 1.2 with .Net framework 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by disabling TLS 1.0 and lower?

What you can do is to enable/set as default TLS 1.2 in your Global.asax file and it should do the job.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Just make sure that `System.Net` is imported

#### Edited:

If Enum value is missing you can try to do next

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;//SecurityProtocolType.Tls1.2;
```

Bad news here is that you might need to replace System.dll with 4.5 version according to [this post](http://joymonscode.blogspot.com/2015/08/how-to-make-net-40-45-use-tls-12.html)